# Are there any undergraduate research/internship opportunities in math/science education/history?

Tags: mathematics, philosophy-of-science

(Apologies if this isn't the right place for such a post. I see lots of information out there for math/science students wanting to do research, but haven't seen anything about doing things on the "soft" side, like history and pedagogy.)

I'm an undergrad math student (will have one more term left after the summer) and I'm hoping to get some advice on summer plans. While I really like math, and I'm considering grad school, I've always been really interested in science education, science in pop culture, and the history of science. I love the book *A Short History of Nearly Everything* and Youtube channels like Vsauce. Working as a science writer or museum curator would probably be a dream job for me. I'm hoping to do something in that realm in the future.

Does anyone know of any good ways to get involved in this sort of thing? It seems like people in this arena come from a pretty wide range of backgrounds. When I think about the parts of math and science that I really like, I keep coming back to the historical, cultural, philosophical, and pedagogical aspects, so something along those lines would be awesome.

I'm living in Canada right now, but I'd love to travel so I'm open to any location. I also have good grades (just under 4.0), if that matters for anything. That said, I'm really open to anything, academia or otherwise.

~~~

If anyone has any suggestions I would be very grateful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: perhaps the academia site would be better suited? I've never really used that site before so I'm not sure if it's on topic there or not.

Comment: There was one [REU in History of Mathematics](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/a-locally-compact-reu-in-the-history-of-mathematics-involving-undergraduates-in-research-preparation) experiment in 2010, but I have not heard of anything more recent. People on [Mathematics Educators SE](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions) may be in a better position to help you on Math Ed.